# Python:Plotting a bubble chart of location data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a list with a pair of tuples to represent the x and y coordinates of location for a GPS log. This is simply like [(x1, y1), (x2,y2), (x3, y3)....].

There can be several repetition of the same (x,y) location in the list. Now, what I want to do is to draw a figure representing these locations and also show the relative frequency, i.e places visited most often. I would guess either a bubble chart with the size of bubble representing the number of times the place is visited or a heatmap would be the most useful way.

What would be the simplest way to do this in python using the matplotlib library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections#collections.Counter) to count the frequency of `(x,y)` pairs.
Use [plt.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)'s `s` parameter to control the sizes, and the `c` parameter to control the colors. Both the `s` and `c` parameters can take a sequence as their argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections
import numpy as np

data = [tuple(pair)
        for pair in np.random.uniform(5, size=(20,2))
        for c in range(np.random.random_integers(50))]
count = collections.Counter(data)

points = count.keys()
x, y = zip(*points)
sizes = np.array(count.values())**2
plt.scatter(x, y, s=sizes, marker='o', c=sizes)
plt.show()
```

[image]